# How to draw a polyline with initial point in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I'm using custom polyline drawer from Leaflet.draw

```
let polylineDrawer = new L.Draw.Polyline(map, {})

polylineDrawer.enable()
```

I need to programmatically add starting point to polyline

I've tried calling `addVertex` of `L.Draw.Polyline`. Looks like it's doesn't work with custom polyline drawer cause of `addHooks` or something... Tried to change sources, no results.

Also tried firing `click` on map after drawer is enabled. Like so:

```
let point = new L.LatLng(x, y)

map.fireEvent('click', {
  latlng: point,
  layerPoint: map.latLngToLayerPoint(point),
  containerPoint: map.latLngToContainerPoint(point),
})
```

Also doesn't work

EDIT: Actually, `AddVertex` does work with custom polylines. It "didn't work" because I passed wrong arguments in my function. Somehow, I missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `addVertex` on your drawer object does let you add a starting point to your line :

```
var polylineDrawer = new L.Draw.Polyline(map, {})
polylineDrawer.enable();

var latlng = L.latLng(48.8583736, 2.2922926);
polylineDrawer.addVertex(latlng);
```

and a demo

```js
var style = {
    stroke: true,
    color: 'red',
    weight: 4,
    opacity: 0.5
};
var map = L.map(document.getElementById('map')).setView([48.8583736, 2.2922926], 15);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var drawnItems = new L.geoJson(null, {style: style}).addTo(map);

map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (event) {
    var layer = event.layer;
    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
});

var polylineDrawer = new L.Draw.Polyline(map, {})
polylineDrawer.enable();

var latlng = L.latLng(48.8583736, 2.2922926);
polylineDrawer.addVertex(latlng);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log==" crossorigin=""></script>
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.12/leaflet.draw.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.12/leaflet.draw.js"></script>

<div id='map'></div>
```